# PHP: Has this code performance issues? Can be improved?

Tags: php, regex, performance, url

I'm trying to make some SEO improvement on my site. I'd like to add some text to my URLs. I'm trying to add information to the URLs. I get the "product name" (or title) from an item and append it to the URL. So, if a "Core 2 Duo 8600 CPU" has id 10, the old URL was:

```
example.com/cpu/10
```

Now, i want to append the product name, so it will be:

```
example.com/cpu/10/core-2-duo-8600-CPU/
```

The problem is that i don't want special chars in there, nor accented words (it's a spanish site), so i built this function:

```
function makeFriendlyURL($string){
        $search = explode(",","ç,æ,œ,á,é,í,ó,ú,à,è,ì,ò,ù,ä,ë,ï,ö,ü,ÿ,â,ê,î,ô,û,å,e,i,ø,u");
        $replace = explode(",","c,ae,oe,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u,y,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u");
        $string = str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
        $string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/"," ",$string);
        $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-',trim($string)); 
        return strtolower($string);
    }
makeFriendlyURL('Técnico electricista') //tecnico-electricista  (accented é is replaced with e)
makeFriendlyURL('RAM 1066/1333') // ram-1066-1333 (striped the slash and lowercase "RAM")
```

Now, do you see any issue? I think it could be improved, but don't know how.

Comment: another pointless performance question

Comment: Ok, if getting help is pointless please remove all your questions.

Comment: you don't need any help, silly. because there is no problem to solve.

Comment: I really don't know that. That's why i'm here. If you check the answer bellow, in three lines he solved it. And just 1 regex check. That's better that what i had. So, it helped me. Your comment did not help me. I thought this place was to help people.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Shraps is back! I kind of missed you! Things were kind of boring without you and Noah. And I still have to figure out what country you're from. Good to see you're still as rude as always :)

Comment: look, I am not trying to insult you or whatever. i am not accusing you for asking pointless questions. but your question indeed pointless. I just state it. Not every question deserves a [positive] answer and not every answer can be counted as help. Sometimes you get way more help from a negative answer. Like in your case. You have to learn to distinguish important matters from negligible ones. In case of performance issues it's easy: ask such a question if something went wrong. Or, if you want to foresee some problem - ask if you're dealing with big amounts of data. a dozen characters aren't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Can this code be improved?**

In these situations it's easier to define with what you want than what you don't want, as that is an every changing list.

This is typical code that will create a slug from a title:

```
// translate accented chars
$search = explode(",","ç,æ,œ,á,é,í,ó,ú,à,è,ì,ò,ù,ä,ë,ï,ö,ü,ÿ,â,ê,î,ô,û,å,e,i,ø,u");
$replace = explode(",","c,ae,oe,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u,y,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u");
$string = str_replace($search, $replace, $string);

// create slug by replacing non-alphanumeric chars with a dash
$slug = trim(preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/', '-', strtolower($string)), '-');
```

**Note:** as a URL, I've added `strtolower()`. Feel free to remove it if you truly want capitals in your URL.

Comment: Thank you Jason, but it has one problems. It replaces the accented chars with "-". So "técnico" will be: "t-cnico". Anyway, it's really compact, i suppose i could replace accented words first and after that apply this function.

Comment: Yes good point. I *over compacted* it by removing the accented chars. See update.

Comment: Shouldn't the `trim()` be on $string, rather than the result of the preg_replace? There won't be any whitespaces since they will be replaced with '-'.

Comment: No, it's right. Note the second parameter. While spaces would indeed be replaced, consider the original title of `#some title`. You wouldn't want a slug of `-some-title`.

Comment: Yep, you're right, I missed that. No idea about the downvote, but my money would be on Shrapnel, who expresses his contempt for minor performance optimizations.

Comment: @EboMike, if that's the case I get downvoted for helping. Nice fallout.